# Can't access shared libraries when running with sudo

Tags: debian, software-development, c, sudo

I'm trying to get a demo working writing PCM to the I<sup>2</sup>S; I've created a small demo program that gives an error when I run with the following command `./demo stereo_small.wav`

```
can't open /dev/mem
```

So I run with the this command `sudo ./demo stereo_small.wav` *(added `sudo`)* and the demo should now be able to run successfully with elevated privileges.

But I now get this error:

```
./demo: error while loading shared libraries: libsndfile.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Initially, to get the program working, I had to execute this command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` just to get it to work, and now the error has returned, but only when I prefix the command with `sudo`

Please bare with me I've only been using C & Linux for a few hours!

**Here's what I've done to compile and run:**

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags sndfile` -c demo.c
gcc 'pkg-config --libs sndfile' demo.o -o demo
sudo ./demo stereo_small.wav
```

**Update - Cause:**
*some environment variables aren't maintained under the SU context see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/232231)*

Comment: The `linux` tag is probably redundant. It would be better if you provided your distribution instead (probably Debian).

Comment: Are you sure that `libsndfile` is where you think it is? Check that directory. Also check the output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` matches it.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with `/dev/mem`?

Comment: I'm trying to write to the GPIO/I2S outputs! see here: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=8496

Comment: I like to throw myself in at the deep-end!

Comment: It looks like sudo ignores environment variables? or some of them.. http://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables

Comment: That's okay. Just add it to the path variable. Or change to root with `sudo -s`, that should maintain your environment.

Comment: I made a change to my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /dev`?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: lol I hope you don't want him to post that here. FYI, mem is `rw` for `root` and `r` for group, and the group is `kmem`.

Comment: Can you try adding the `/usr/local/lib` to the path variable like this `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: @Jivings You probably shouldn't need to be root to write GPIOs, so I was trying to figure out the root cause. Having said that, that command may have been a little verbose...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack until I figure out how to compile and link correctly or move the requirement for sudo from the 'finished' code; but here is one option...

run the shell under sudo and add set the environment variable before executing the program:

```
sudo bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
./demo stereo_small.wav
```

Comment: Instead of `sudo bash` you can keep the current shell with `sudo -s`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `su` instead of `sudo` then you can pass a command to the root shell for it to execute:

```
su --command="export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib && ./demo stereo_small.wav"
```

The problem with using `sudo` is that the variable we're trying to export does persist across to the root shell. I'm not really sure why.

Comment: still get the error while loading shared libraries :(

Answer (score 0):

It is true that `sudo` "drops" the Environment Variables for security reasons (further reading [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226076/201132)).

However, as suggested in this [great answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/57938/658154) you can pass environment variables along with your call to `sudo`. In your case, this would look something like this:

```
sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./demo stereo_small.wav
```

That is, pass your environment variable(s) in the form `VAR=VALUE`. This I consider is better as it avoids using `su` and other "hacky" approaches.